# shared ssh session for many clients (Java)

Tags: java, ssh

I have my CLIENT (one or more) that access one WEB SERVER that manages another SERVER using commands received by the client.

My question is.
Instead of having multiples ssh connection (one per client) between the web server and the final server, is it possible to share this ssh connection  if I use more than one client?

Instead of

```
Client 1       WebServer              Server
------------>    Conn1    -----------> 

Client 2       WebServer              Server
------------>    Conn2    ----------->
```

Get this

```
Client 1       WebServer ->             Server
------------>             
                              CONN  ---->  
Client 2       WebServer ->              Server
------------>
```

Thanks in advance